# linux. how to preserve lines when setting content of file to environment variable?

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables, newline

I have a file with several lines.
When using cat/more/less [file] in the shell,
the content is shown line by line

When doing the following commands:

```
temp=`cat [file]`
echo $temp
```

the content is shown in one line.

Is there a way to preserve the line endings when setting to environment variable and then echo it?

Thanks

Comment: `temp` is a variable.  It may or may not be in the environment, and its status is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes:

```
temp=`cat [file]`
echo "$temp"
```

The magic is in the quotes around `$temp`; without them, `echo` gets these arguments:

```
echo line1\nline2\nlin3
```

The shell parsing algorithm will split the command line at white space, so `echo` sees three arguments. If you quote the variable, `echo` will see a single argument and the shell parsing won't touch the whitespace between the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a super-precise answer: Process substitution into a variable will **not** preserve:

- Any ASCII NULs
- Any number of trailing newlines

Only the latter can be worked around:

```
temp=$(realprocess; echo x)  ## Add x to the end to preserve trailing newlines
temp=${temp%x}  ## Remove the x again (keeping originally trailing newlines)
```

When you want to display the true contents of a variable, use `printf`. `echo` adds an additional newline, and is not reliable (when the input starts with the string `-n` for example).

In any case, always quote your variables, or the shell will split them on whitespace to any number of arguments!

```
printf %s "$temp"
```

Generally, keeping the complete contents of a file in a shell variable is not what you want. There is files for that.

Answer (score -1):

If I do the following the newlines are preserved:

```
echo a >> test
echo b >> test
temp=`cat test`
echo $temp
```

Comment: As it states above, you need to quote your variables when accesing them if you want the newlines preserved. You should change the last line (echo $temp) to (echo "$temp") and then it would work as you suggest. However, if you access the file 'test' in another environment or program (for example. Windows' cmd.exe prompt: you can just type 'type test') the newlines are preserved in _the_file_ but the question above asks how to get it working with the linux 'echo' command...  echo pushes the lines together much like the line continuation character was used (\)...btw i didnt downvote ya :)